# loop for update not working

Tags: php

i am trying to update with a loop through $_post data,  but the update is not working

```
require_once("include/session.php");
require_once("include/dataconnect.php"); 
require_once("include/functions.php"); 
if(array_key_exists('item', $_POST)){
    $items = $_POST['item'];
    //Loop through $_POST items, updating the database for each item
    foreach ($items as $item) { 
        $Pquantity = intval($item[0]);
        $Pidno = intval($item[1]);
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
            UPDATE repplac
                 SET Pquantity = {$Pquantity}
                 WHERE
                       Pidno = {$Pidno}
                 AND
                       username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        "); 
    }
```

this is the form that sends the data

```
 echo "
<form action='updatepplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>SHOP NAME</th>
    <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
    <th>PRODUCT SIZE</th>
    <th>PRODUCT COLOUR</th>
    <th>PRODUCT QUANTITY</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>";
```

// Get DB results and loop, outputting table rows with counter

```
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac") or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult); $i++) 
{
    echo "
      <tr>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Sname'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pname'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Psize'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pcolour'])."</td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' name='item[$i][Pquantity]' id='Pquantity' 
    value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pquantity'])."' />
          <input type='hidden' name='item[$i][Pidno]' id='Pidno' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."' />
        </td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Price'])."</td>
        <td><a href='deleteproduct.php?del=".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."'>delete</a></td>
      </tr>";
  }
```

Comment: Echo the sql query to yourself and take a look at it. If it is correct then perfrom mysql_query(.. your query ..) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: What does "not working" mean? My crystal ball is in the shop today.

Comment: In addition to echo'ing the query, when you add `or die(mysql_error())` to your `mysql_query`, what does it tell you?

Comment: when i echo the querry it comes back with the old data, and not the updated data

Comment: @lostty84  `it comes back with the old data` this data is from the form. may be you are sending from the form not the data you need.

Comment: What is the value of `$queryreg`? Are there any MySQL errors? What is the output of `vardump($_POST['item']);`?

Comment: @Cheery i am tring to pull the $_post data sent from the updated form into the former db

Comment: @lostty84 I understand what you are talking about. But you told me that your sql query contains an old data, not the one you want to update your database with.

Comment: @Cheery YOU ARE RIGHT, but when i use "<pre>";print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";, it prints the new data, i want from the post data

Comment: @j08691 when the value in the quantity is changed the new value in the  form is not passed to the db

Answer (score 1):

Store $_SESSION['username'] in a variable first then use it in the query. So your query should be something like 
 
`$username = $_SESSION['username'];`

$queryreg = mysql_query("UPDATE repplac SET Pquantity = '$Pquantity' WHERE Pidno = '$Pidno' AND username = '$username'");

Comment: i assignd the value in the loop but did not give a result am i doing it right

Comment: could you paste the html code that is used in getting the items post data

Comment: "<pre>";print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";

Comment: or is it the form you re asking for

Comment: i have edited the question and pasted the form at the bottom of the question(but  did not get ow to post it well)